# � character from ldap

Tags: php, utf-8, ldap, character

i am getting some strange characters form ldap server when i search some user  info.if value contains turkish characters like 'ç' it replaces to '�'.in this situatian i convert string to utf-8 than str_replace to fix it.My function is that;

```
 function utf8char($str) {     
    $search = array('Ý','ý', 'þ' ,'Þ' ,'ð','Ð');
    $replace = array('İ' ,'ı' ,'ş','Ş','ğ','Ğ');
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
}
```

But sometimes that causes some problem , so i have to detect if string contains '�' character to fix it.strpos does not work.Can anyone say something about this? And what is this shit '�' character , i would be happy if anyone can explain...

Edit: Here is my code snippet;

```
$name = $ldapHandler->get_user_info('username')['name'];
echo $name;
echo utf8_decode($name);
echo mb_convert_encoding($name,'utf-8');
echo utf8char(mb_convert_encoding($name,'utf-8'));
```

and output of this code;

```
Bilgi ��lem Daire Ba�kanl���
Bilgi ?lem Daire Ba?kanl??
Bilgi Ýþlem Daire Baþkanlýðý
Bilgi İşlem Daire Başkanlığı (this is the correct string)
```

Comment: What's your default encoding? And what's your PHP-Version? It looks like you get ISO-8859-9 encoded data and try to output that in UTF-8. What does ```echo utf8_encode($name)``` result in?

Comment: if i can rely on mb_detect_encoding($name) the record comes with UTF-8 and utf8_encode($name) returns Bilgi ?lem Daire Ba?kanl??

Comment: and whats your internal encoding in php set to? and in what encoding are the source files stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time but i decided to share my solution who faced with the same problem.

This function worked for me:

```
function repair($value) {

    $res = @iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $value);

    if (strlen($value) != strlen($res)) {
        return w1250_to_utf8($value);
    }

    return $res;
}

function w1250_to_utf8($text) {
    // map based on:
    // http://konfiguracja.c0.pl/iso02vscp1250en.html
    // http://konfiguracja.c0.pl/webpl/index_en.html#examp
    // http://www.htmlentities.com/html/entities/
    $map = array(
        chr(0x8A) => chr(0xA9),
        chr(0x8C) => chr(0xA6),
        chr(0x8D) => chr(0xAB),
        chr(0x8E) => chr(0xAE),
        chr(0x8F) => chr(0xAC),
        chr(0x9C) => chr(0xB6),
        chr(0x9D) => chr(0xBB),
        chr(0xA1) => chr(0xB7),
        chr(0xA5) => chr(0xA1),
        chr(0xBC) => chr(0xA5),
        chr(0x9F) => chr(0xBC),
        chr(0xB9) => chr(0xB1),
        chr(0x9A) => chr(0xB9),
        chr(0xBE) => chr(0xB5),
        chr(0x9E) => chr(0xBE),
        chr(0x80) => '&euro;',
        chr(0x82) => '&sbquo;',
        chr(0x84) => '&bdquo;',
        chr(0x85) => '&hellip;',
        chr(0x86) => '&dagger;',
        chr(0x87) => '&Dagger;',
        chr(0x89) => '&permil;',
        chr(0x8B) => '&lsaquo;',
        chr(0x91) => '&lsquo;',
        chr(0x92) => '&rsquo;',
        chr(0x93) => '&ldquo;',
        chr(0x94) => '&rdquo;',
        chr(0x95) => '&bull;',
        chr(0x96) => '&ndash;',
        chr(0x97) => '&mdash;',
        chr(0x99) => '&trade;',
        chr(0x9B) => '&rsquo;',
        chr(0xA6) => '&brvbar;',
        chr(0xA9) => '&copy;',
        chr(0xAB) => '&laquo;',
        chr(0xAE) => '&reg;',
        chr(0xB1) => '&plusmn;',
        chr(0xB5) => '&micro;',
        chr(0xB6) => '&para;',
        chr(0xB7) => '&middot;',
        chr(0xBB) => '&raquo;',
    );

    $search = array('Ý', 'ý', 'þ', 'Þ', 'ð', 'Ð');
    $replace = array('İ', 'ı', 'ş', 'Ş', 'ğ', 'Ğ');

    mb_internal_encoding("ISO-8859-1");
    return str_replace($search, $replace, html_entity_decode(mb_convert_encoding(strtr($text, $map), 'UTF-8'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use utf8_encode() while storing it into the db. and at the time fetching use utf8_decode().

Comment: i dont store anything , i am only retrieving and displaying some records... i edited my question with your answer.

Comment: en- and decoding to and from UTF-8 without knowing what happens in the background can help. But most of the time it makes things worse. You should always try to find the cause for what is happening to be then able to fix it.